# Move PERC5I and RAID Array from Gen 2 to Gen 3 2950

Tags: raid, dell-perc

I have two 2950 servers, one Gen 2 and one Gen 3.  The Gen 2 server has a failed motherboard DT021, and a lot of important data.  The Gen 3 box is currently unused.  It has a DP246 motherboard.

My question: Is it possible and safe to move the PERC5I WX072 controller and RAID 5 array drives from the Gen 2 box to the Gen 3 box and retain the RAID array intact?  Is this a fairly safe procedure, and is there anything to watch out for?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should be absolutely fine, the one obvious thing you should do to be safe is to back up all the data first.  Just in case the worst does accidentally happen.  Something could always fault and its better safe than sorry.

Another trick is to label the drives so they all go back in, in the correct drive bay.

Comment: You should always have backups, whether you're transplanting your RAID arrays or not.

Comment: You say that, and I completely agree, but how many people truly listen.  Its just worth mentioning.  Yes, this should go just fine, but all the data needs to be safe offsite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work fine. The RAID configuration is stored on the card and on the disks themselves, and is not dependent on the motherboard.

If you don't reconnect the drives in the same order, then you might have to reimport the array, but that's pretty trivial.

The most probable way to lose data in this scenario is by dropping all the hard drives on the floor.

Comment: Any thoughts on the difference between the motherboards?  I am assuming that I can bring up the Windows install which came from the Gen 2 box on the Gen 3 box, and just update drivers as needed.  It is server 2003 R2.

Comment: I have no idea what old versions of Windows do when you replace a motherboard. I would expect trouble with anything before 2008.

Comment: The most troublesome part of switching motherboard with Windows 2000 and 2003 is the storage drivers. Since you are moving the controller, too, this probably won't be a problem.